# Adding time and date to google calendar via intent

Tags: java, android, date, time, calendar

I am currently trying to add an event to the google `calendar` using an object which I have stored on my database. The date stored on the database is stored in the format of Date and the time is stored as a string.

Currently everything is working bar the time portion of the event. The date is being passed correctly but the time is defaulting to 0:00. How would I make it so the time is passed properly?

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
if(arg0.getId() == R.id.btnAddToCal)
 { 

    long startTime = 0, endTime=0;

    String startDate = blankevent.EventDate;
    try {
        Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(startDate);
        startTime=date.getTime();
    }
    catch(Exception e){ }   


    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
    Intent calintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    calintent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    calintent.putExtra("eventLocation", blankevent.EventLocation);
    calintent.putExtra("title", blankevent.EventName);
    calintent.putExtra("description", blankevent.EventDetails);

    calintent.putExtra("beginTime",startTime);
    calintent.putExtra("dtstart", blankevent.EventTime);

  startActivity(calintent);
   return;
 }
```

I have attached a screenshot of the actual problem area. The date is correct but the time i incorrect.

[image]

Solved code

```
@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.e("cal","sel2");
    if(arg0.getId() == R.id.btnAddToCal)
     { 

        String startDate = blankevent.EventDate;
        String startHour = blankevent.EventTime;
        Date fulldate = null;

        try {
            fulldate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm").parse(startDate+"-"+startHour);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
        Intent calintent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        calintent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
        calintent.putExtra("eventLocation", blankevent.EventLocation);
        calintent.putExtra("title", blankevent.EventName);
        calintent.putExtra("description", blankevent.EventDetails);
        calintent.putExtra("beginTime",  fulldate.getTime());   
        calintent.putExtra("endTime",fulldate.getTime()+60*60*1000);


      startActivity(calintent);
       return;
     }
```

Comment: Where should it be getting `startTime`? Your `SimpleDateFormat` parser will only get the year, month, and day.

Comment: Your date parse string is wrong, yyyy-mm-dd, means year, minute and day-of-month. should be yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: startTime is the parsed output of EventDate. EventDate is a field stored in the format YYYY-MM-DD in my database and I have an EventTime field stored as a string in the form HH:MM. 

the yyyy-MM-dd error was my own mistake when typing this out, it is correct in the actual code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Starttime needs to be miliseconds. Also i dont really get your intent extra fields names.

Since you only parse dd--MM--YYYY the time is still left at 00:00 , and the default duration of a event is 1 hour.
So you probably just have to set the Time of your Date object (startTime) and then call startTime.getMillis();

```
String startDate = blankevent.EventDate;
String startHour = blankevent.EventTime;
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd-HH:mm").parse(startDate+"-"+startHour);
```

Also, 
Here is a clean example from [www.developer.com By Lauren Darcey & Shane Conder](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/android-calendaring-tutorial-android-4.0.html)

```
Intent calIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
calIntent.setData(Events.CONTENT_URI);
calIntent.putExtra(Events.TITLE, "Google IO Afterparty");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.EVENT_LOCATION, "The W Hotel Bar on Third Street");
calIntent.putExtra(Events.DESCRIPTION, "Hang out after Google IO for a drink and geeky conversation.");
Calendar startTime = Calendar.getInstance();
startTime.set(2012, 5, 29, 18, 0);
Calendar endTime = Calendar.getInstance();
endTime.set(2012, 5, 29, 22, 30);
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
startTime.getTimeInMillis());
calIntent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
endTime.getTimeInMillis());
startActivity(calIntent);
```

Comment: The extra field names are fields from a retrieved object from a database. It would make sense in the context of the rest of the application.

Comment: check the 3 Lines of codes i added to my answer, if really the only problem you are having is the Time not set correctly, this should fix it.

Comment: I have tried those 3 extra lines. It seems to be working. I made a log to check the format and it is 

02-15 15:28:31.300: E/callog(20057): sel2Thu Jan 10 22:00:00 GMT 2013


However it is not passing to the actual calendar

Comment: Solved it! 

calintent.putExtra("beginTime",  fulldate.getTime());   
calintent.putExtra("endTime",fulldate.getTime()+60*60*1000);


I will edit my answer to my working code. Thank you so much!