# Syncing my custom android calendar with Google Calendar

Tags: android, calendar

I'm getting a lot of how to signup for Google Apps when googling for this.

I've made a CalendarView. I have a listview which shows times in the day that have been taken or are available. When you select a date and time, you create an appointment at that time.

How can I sync with Google Calendar to show that my app has made an appointment at that time? I need to send data to Google I know, but what and how?

Comment: Literally nothing. I don't even know where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code to add an event to the calendar using Intents

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();              
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
intent.putExtra("beginTime", cal.getTimeInMillis());
intent.putExtra("allDay", true);
intent.putExtra("rrule", "FREQ=YEARLY");
intent.putExtra("endTime", cal.getTimeInMillis()+60*60*1000);
intent.putExtra("title", "A Test Event from android app");
startActivity(intent);
```

More details: [Adding time and date to google calendar via intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14896768/solvedadding-time-and-date-to-google-calendar-via-intent)

Good luck

Comment: Only reason your not getting an upvote is I'm to low in rep to do so. Thanks for the link!